# Cakephp search conditions for non-existent table entries

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and trying to find Users who have not configured options. If there is no entry found for User 1 in the options table, then that user should be selected

The tables

```
users
id    |    username   |      password     |category_id    |     registration_date    


options
id    |    user_id    |    display_email   |    allow_contact
```

A user does not have to be entered in the options table. What I'm trying to do is find all of the users that do not have an entry in the options table.

```
$this->paginate = array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'User.category_id' => $category_id,
                            //condition if the options table entry for the user is not set
                        ),
                        'joins' => array(
                            array(
                                 'table' => 'options',
                                 'alias' => 'Option',
                                 'type' => 'inner',
                                 'conditions' => array(
                                      'Option.user_id' => 'User.id'
                                 )
                            )
                        )
                     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your join type to left.  This will get you all users, even those that have no options.  An inner join will only get those users that have an option -- almost the opposite of what you want.

Then add a condition to look for rows where Option.id is null.  Users that do not have an option associated with them will have null for all the columns that came from Option.

```
$this->paginate = array(
       'conditions' => array(
              'User.category_id' => $category_id,
              'Option.id' => null
        ),
        'joins' => array(
               array(
                     'table' => 'options',
                     'alias' => 'Option',
                     'type' => 'left',
                     'conditions' => array(
                           'Option.user_id' => 'User.id'
                      )
               )
        )
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I'm embarrassed to admit but wasn't quite sure about the inner/left/right joins. I've read about them, but I didn't quite grasp the differences.

Comment: This image helps me to understand them http://i.stack.imgur.com/66zgg.png -- each circle represents the set of results for one of the two associated tables.  Where the circles intersect is those rows in table A that also have data associated with them in table B.  The red is that portion of the tables you're trying to get through your query.